# The tag [orthodoxism] is not orthodox

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

I've always been uncomfortable with the [orthodoxism](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthodoxism) tag here. It's a nonstandard term for what is normally called "Orthodoxy". The questions we have here appear to all relate to what is known as Eastern Orthodox Christianity.

I propose that we rename the [orthodoxism](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthodoxism) tag to [eastern-orthodox](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eastern-orthodox), which will harmonize us with Christianity Stack Exchange, which uses the tag [[Eastern Orthodox]](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eastern-orthodox).

I know that I am a moderator and can do this myself, but I want to gauge the community's opinion before I move ahead. Are there any particular reasons why [eastern-orthodox](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eastern-orthodox) is not the best tag to move to? Are there other tags we should consider?

Comment: Now that you've pointed it out, I'm not gonna be able to unsee it. Yuk!

Answer (score 6):

I completely agree that this is a problem.

Not sure I fully agree with the proposed name. The difference between our site and Christianity is of course that for every tag there, there is an implied "Christianity" as part of that tag. In that context "eastern-orthodox-christianity" scans quite well. You'd normally fully say the name as "Eastern Orthodox Church", but in the context of discussing Christianity, that last word is arguably redundant.

Here there's instead an implied "History" on every tag. "eastern-orthodox-history" ... I mean its OK, but seems to be missing some context.

Also, the other similar tags we have I'd say are [christianity](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christianity) and (more applicable) [catholic-church](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholic-church). So from  this standpoint the most consistent would perhaps be [eastern-orthodox-church](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eastern-orthodox-church)

Comment: Drawback to this approach: There are some churches (most notably the Ukranian Orthodox Church) that use the Eastern rite, but are technically under the Catholic Pope. So splitting on churches rather than heritages/rites can yield different results, and that's probably not what someone's expecting.

Comment: @TED: You mean the [Ukrainian Greek Catholic Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_Greek_Catholic_Church)? (As opposed to the [Orthodox Church of Ukraine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthodox_Church_of_Ukraine), which is an autocephalous Eastern Orthodox church — not to be confused with the [Ukrainian Orthodox Church (Moscow Patriarchate)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_Orthodox_Church_(Moscow_Patriarchate)) or the breakaway [Ukrainian Orthodox Church (Kyiv Patriarchate)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_Orthodox_Church_%E2%80%93_Kyiv_Patriarchate).)

Answer (score 1):

The religion is not the same thing as the institution - Catholicism is not the same thing as the Roman Catholic Church. The beliefs known collectively as Orthodox are not the same thing as the Eastern Orthodox Church.

If they're two things, they need two names. *Orthodox Christianity* does not work because it could describe mainline Christian beliefs in any denomination - and the history of beliefs-now-held-by-Orthodox-churches would presumably include some heterodox Christians who, broadly speaking, were much closer to beliefs-now-held-by-Orthodox-churches.

*Eastern Orthodox Christianity* also does not work because it excludes beliefs-now-held-by-Orthodox-churches which are not part of the Eastern Orthodox Church. The Ethiopian Orthodox church is an example.

You said that the name was 'non-Standard'. It is not always wrong to call something a different name to what it calls itself. It should only not be done if the name is in some way offensive.

For instance we shouldn't change the Catholicism tag to 'papism', even though 'papism' is shorter, because it is an offensive term. If you can show us someone prominent who says 'don't call our beliefs Orthodoxism, it's offensive', then fine. We will have to come up with something wordier. If not, we should stick with Orthodoxism.